# date format Calendar in Android

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

This is how it is written, I want to change the way it is written. I want it to be written in Turkish as Friday Mar 27. Returns null when I change the spelling in SimpleDateFormat. I am printing the data I have pulled from the database.

**The output I want is:** `Cuma Mar 27`(Turkish)

Database output:

```
date ":" 2019-11-27 14: 42: 23.000000 "," timezone_type ": 3," timezone ":" UTC "
```

Android output:

```
Fri Mar 27 14:42:23 GMT+03:00 2020
```

Code:

```java
JSONObject form_tarih2 = jObj.getJSONObject("form_tarih2");
String date = form_tarih2.getString("date");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", 
        java.util.Locale.getDefault());
Date calculateDate = sdf.parse(date);
tarihstring = calculateDate;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
calendar.setTime(sdf.parse(String.valueOf(tarihstring)));

calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH,4);
Date future = calendar.getTime();
```

Comment: can you please tell me the input date and desired output which you want?

Comment: I updated the topic

Comment: Can you please tell what is this Çar Kas 27?I am getting this output

Comment: do you want to add 4 more months?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: @AfzalKhan That’s *Wed Nov 27*, so the expected result before adding 4 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

```
    DateTimeFormatter jsonDateFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
    DateTimeFormatter turkishDateFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE MMM d", Locale.forLanguageTag("tr"));
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Istanbul");

    String dateFromJson = "2019-11-27 14:42:23.000000";
    String timezoneTypeFromJson = "3";
    String timezoneFromJson = "UTC";

    if (! timezoneTypeFromJson.equals("3")) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("This Stack Overflow answer only supports timezone_type 3");
    }
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateFromJson, jsonDateFormatter);
    ZoneId jsonZone = ZoneId.of(timezoneFromJson);
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = ldt.atZone(jsonZone).withZoneSameInstant(zone);
    ZonedDateTime futureDateTime = dateTime.plusMonths(4);
    String wantedDateString = futureDateTime.format(turkishDateFormatter);

    System.out.println(wantedDateString);
```

Output is the desired:

> Cuma Mar 27

(Turkish for *Friday Mar 27*)

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17711005/5772882) timezone_type 3 really means a time zone ID in the form of *region/city*, for example Europe/London or Etc/UTC. `UTC` is an alias to `Etc/UTC`, so works too.

If you didn’t want the result in Istanbul time zone, just fill a different one into the code.

`SimpleDateFormat` is notoriously troublesome and also cannot parse a date-time string with 6 decimals on the seconds (it only supports 3 decimals). It is also long outdated. `Date` and `Calendar` too are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead of those classes I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

### Or use a built-in localized format

You wanted your date printed with the day of week and with the year left out. For this purpose you need to hand specify the format as I do above. So mostly for other readers: for most purposes a built-in format is suitable and has two potential advantages: it fits the users’ expectations well and it lends itself well to internationalization. For example:

```
    DateTimeFormatter turkishDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG)
            .withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("tr"));
```

> 27 Mart 2020 Cuma

Or shorter:

```
    DateTimeFormatter turkishDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
            .withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("tr"));
```

> 27.Mar.2020

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Answer by vascowhite about `timezone_type`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17711005/5772882)
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: Good Answer. I would also add a mention of using [`DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDate(java.time.format.FormatStyle)) to automatically localize rather than hard-code a format for output.

Answer (score -1):

Use this to convert dates. Make it static to use anywhere from the app

```
        String s=getFormatedTime("2019-11-27 14: 42: 23.000000","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS","EEEE MMM dd");
```

your function:-

```
public static String getFormatedTime(String dateStr, String strReadFormat, String strWriteFormat) {
    if (dateStr == null) return "";
    String formattedDate = dateStr;

    DateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(strReadFormat, Locale.getDefault());
    DateFormat writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(strWriteFormat, new Locale("tr"));

    Date date = null;

    try {
        date = readFormat.parse(dateStr);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    }

    if (date != null) {
        formattedDate = writeFormat.format(date);
    }

    return formattedDate;
}
```

you can add 4 more months in the result