# Check if a string representing a datetime includes a timezone

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetimeoffset

I'd like to parse a string to an object representing a timestamp, but I'm having some trouble adding the right timezone to it.

Specifically, when parsing, I can't find a way to make a distinction between strings that have a timezone-offset added, and those that don't.

### Use case

I'm reading in several xml-files. In those files, several timestamps are present, which can be either UTC, in my local timezone, or some third timezone.
Or they may not have any timezone-information as part of the string, in which case we should fall back to a default-timezone, specified elsewhere in the xml. That default can, again, be either UTC, my local timezone, or a third zone.
Ultimately, I want to translate all of these timestamps to UTC.

So, I may have the following data (on a PC with system-timezone Europe/Amsterdam, currently UTC+2):

File_one.xml

```
<data>
  <timestamp eventName="First">2023-5-1T12:01:00Z</timestamp>
  <timestamp eventName="Second">2023-5-1T12:02:00+02:00</timestamp>
  <timestamp eventName="Third">2023-5-1T12:03:00+04:00</timestamp>
  <timestamp eventName="Fourth">2023-5-1T12:04:00</timestamp>
</data>
<configuration>
  <timezone>Europe/Amsterdam</timezone>
</configuration>
```

And file_two.xml

```
<data>
  <timestamp eventName="Fifth">2023-5-1T12:05:00Z</timestamp>
  <timestamp eventName="Sixth">2023-5-1T12:06:00+02:00</timestamp>
  <timestamp eventName="Seventh">2023-5-1T12:07:00+04:00</timestamp>
  <timestamp eventName="Eighth">2023-5-1T12:08:00</timestamp>
</data>
<configuration>
  <timezone>America/New_York</timezone>
</configuration>
```

Which, after all parsing, should result in the following timestamps in UTC:

```
First   2023-05-01T12:01:00
Second  2023-05-01T10:02:00
Third   2023-05-01T08:03:00
Fourth  2023-05-01T10:04:00
Fifth   2023-05-01T12:05:00
Sixth   2023-05-01T10:06:00
Seventh 2023-05-01T08:07:00
Eighth  2023-05-01T16:08:00
```

My main problem, what this question is about, is distinguishing `Eighth` from `Sixth`.

### Approaches that don't work.

I've tried using both `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset`, with their `Parse`/`TryParse`-methods. And both seem to assume my local timezone when parsing the values without a timezone. Adding a timezone later on for values with a local timezone isn't going to work either, because that would mean messing up those values that actually are in my local timezone, i.e. `Second` and `Sixth`.

Another approach I tried was using `TryParseExact` to first parse those values with or without timezone-information, but unfortunately my actual timestamps aren't as tidy as the example here, and I'm not sure about all the exact formats that I can expect. What I would like is just distinguishing between an offset and no offset at all.

(I may have mixed up the words timezone and time-offset. In this context, the difference doesn't really matter)

Comment: I love that you add a  'don't work' section, but maybe next time put in actual code samples of what you tried.

Comment: I would think that you could detect the absence of a time zone with a regular expression. Then append your default time zone to the string before parsing with DateTimeOffset.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar situation so i'll talk about what i did in that case in the hopes that it will send you on the right way. If its completely off, let me know in a comment and i'll remove this.

I'm assuming you have no control over how the files are generated, and you can't  just fix the documents to use a single format including timezone.

I have a couple tabular data files in various formats (excel/csv/tsv/json and more) which all use various formats for date time. I wrote the the following helper method which checks against a bunch of formats for various cases from  most to least-specific.

```cs
public static bool TryParseExactDayMonthYear(ReadOnlySpan<char> s, out DateTime result) => TryParseExactDayMonthYear(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result);

/// <summary>
/// CultureInfo.InvariantCulture uses en-US notation, meaning day/month are twisted compared to the EU.
/// This tries various formats to get at least a D-M-Y datetime.
/// The datetime is set to UTC by default
/// </summary>
/// <param name="s"></param>
/// <param name="provider"></param>
/// <param name="style"></param>
/// <param name="result"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool TryParseExactDayMonthYear(ReadOnlySpan<char> s, IFormatProvider? provider, DateTimeStyles style, out DateTime result)
{
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", provider, style, out result)
        || DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "d-M-yyyy HH:mm", provider, style, out result)
        || DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", provider, style, out result)
        || DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "d-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss", provider, style, out result)
        || DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "d-M-yyyy", provider, style, out result)
        || DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd-MM-yyyy", provider, style, out result)
        || DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "d-M-yy", provider, style, out result)
        || DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd-MM-yy", provider, style, out result)

        // Germany (DerKurrier)
        || DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm", provider, style, out result)
        || DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "d.M.yyyy HH:mm", provider, style, out result)
        || DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", provider, style, out result)
        || DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "d.M.yyyy HH:mm:ss", provider, style, out result)
        || DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "d.M.yyyy", provider, style, out result)
        || DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd.MM.yyyy", provider, style, out result)
        || DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "d.M.yy", provider, style, out result)
        || DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd.MM.yy", provider, style, out result)
        
        // Last resort
        || DateTime.TryParse(s, provider, style, out result)

        // For excel files created on a dutch machine...
        || DateTime.TryParse(s, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL"), style, out result)
       )
    {
        result = DateTime.SpecifyKind(result, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Speed here was not important for me.
I can imagine you can adopt the same approach, passing different formats, timezones and cultures so that your cases are covered. (it's not pretty i know).

Another option i'd consider exploring is using the library NodaTime, [which was created for dealing with these types of situations](https://nodatime.org/2.2.x/userguide/rationale).

See for ex. this doc page:

https://nodatime.org/2.2.x/userguide/type-choices

Nodatime also inclused a timezone db which can work with values like 'Europe/Amsterdam' (which .nets TimeZoneInfo does not use. See for example this snippet that converts a php datetime type to a .net DateTime;

```cs
private static DateTime ParsePhpDateTimeString(string dateString, string timezone, long timezoneType)
{
    var localDateTimePattern = LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff");
    var localDateTime = localDateTimePattern.Parse(dateString).GetValueOrThrow();

    // See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17711005/4122889
    //  Type 1; A UTC offset, such as in new DateTime("17 July 2013 -0300");
    //  Type 2; A timezone abbreviation, such as in new DateTime("17 July 2013 GMT");
    //  Type 3: A timezone identifier, such as in new DateTime("17 July 2013", new DateTimeZone("Europe/London"));

    switch (timezoneType)
    {
        case 1:
            var offSetPattern = OffsetPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("+HH:mm");
            var offset = offSetPattern.Parse(timezone).Value;
            var zonedDateTimeFromOffset = localDateTime.InZoneStrictly(DateTimeZone.ForOffset(offset));
            return zonedDateTimeFromOffset.ToDateTimeUtc();
        case 2:
            throw new NotSupportedException("Not (Yet) support converting from timeZonetype 2 - but doable to add in!");
        case 3:
            var dateTimeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timezone];
            var zonedDateTime = dateTimeZone.AtStrictly(localDateTime);
            var dateTimeUtc = zonedDateTime.ToDateTimeUtc();
            return dateTimeUtc;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(timezoneType));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like an approach I can use as a starting point. I'm going to look into the Nodatime-library, it looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

The input dates consists of just two type:

- unambiguous (`2023-5-1T12:01:00Z`, `2023-5-1T12:02:00+02:00` etc)
- ambiguous (`2023-5-1T12:04:00`, `2023-5-1T12:08:00`)

  - fortunately you know the IANA timezone name

For unambiguous dates you can use `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact`. The result contains necessary information to convert the datetime to UTC.

For ambiguous dates you need to convert the IANA timezone name (Europe/Amsterdam and America/New_York) to something that Windows understand (W. Europe Standard Time and Eastern Standard Time). This could be done with `TimeZoneInfo.TryConvertIanaIdToWindowsId` function but it does not work out of the box.

If you get it to work, you can use `TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset` to get the UTC offset *for that timezone on that particular date*, then build a DateTimeOffset object:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

List<(string dateString, string timezoneName)> tests = new()
{
    ("2023-5-1T12:01:00Z", "Europe/Amsterdam"),
    ("2023-5-1T12:02:00+02:00", "Europe/Amsterdam"),
    ("2023-5-1T12:03:00+04:00", "Europe/Amsterdam"),
    ("2023-5-1T12:04:00", "Europe/Amsterdam"),
    ("2023-5-1T12:05:00Z", "America/New_York"),
    ("2023-5-1T12:06:00+02:00", "America/New_York"),
    ("2023-5-1T12:07:00+04:00", "America/New_York"),
    ("2023-5-1T12:08:00", "America/New_York")
};
foreach (var test in tests)
{
    string dateString = test.dateString;
    string timezoneName = test.timezoneName;
    Regex tzTest = new Regex("(?:Z|[+-]\\d\\d:\\d\\d)$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    DateTimeOffset result;
    if (tzTest.IsMatch(dateString))
    {
        result = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-M-d\\THH:mm:ssK", null);
    }
    else
    {
        TimeZoneInfo.TryConvertIanaIdToWindowsId(timezoneName, out string? timezoneName_w);
        if (timezoneName_w == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Timezone name conversion failed for {timezoneName}");
        }
        DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-M-d\\THH:mm:ss", null);
        TimeSpan offset = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timezoneName_w).GetUtcOffset(datetime);
        result = new DateTimeOffset(datetime, offset);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} => {2}", dateString.PadRight(24), timezoneName.PadRight(20), result.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o"));
}
```

Result:

```
2023-5-1T12:01:00Z       Europe/Amsterdam     => 2023-05-01T12:01:00.0000000+00:00
2023-5-1T12:02:00+02:00  Europe/Amsterdam     => 2023-05-01T10:02:00.0000000+00:00
2023-5-1T12:03:00+04:00  Europe/Amsterdam     => 2023-05-01T08:03:00.0000000+00:00
2023-5-1T12:04:00        Europe/Amsterdam     => 2023-05-01T10:04:00.0000000+00:00
2023-5-1T12:05:00Z       America/New_York     => 2023-05-01T12:05:00.0000000+00:00
2023-5-1T12:06:00+02:00  America/New_York     => 2023-05-01T10:06:00.0000000+00:00
2023-5-1T12:07:00+04:00  America/New_York     => 2023-05-01T08:07:00.0000000+00:00
2023-5-1T12:08:00        America/New_York     => 2023-05-01T16:08:00.0000000+00:00
```